How to make Tab Colors Persist in Visual studio?
Is it possible for the Tab Colors to always persist?  Currently, the color only appears when the tab is selected which is not as helpful.  This question applies to Visual Studio 2022.  The colors currently being applied are fine I would just like them to persist indefinitely.
Please upvote this Feature Request.  Thank you!

Thank you for your feedback.


Is it possible for the Tab Colors to always persist?

I'm afraid not. Looks like  this behavior "the color appears when the tab selected" is by design. If you want to distinguish documents tabs by color to better classify them, you can color tabs in the vertical view:
For example: files in Project 1 are colored pink, files in Project 2 are colored green.

Doc Referred:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/customizing-window-layouts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#colorize-tabs-in-different-views
Besides, i would suggest you can raise a feature request at Developer Community.
That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate product group, and make it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions.

Dou, I mostly want the persistence for Blazor projects with Code behind, which means the files are in the same project.  Specifically I need to be able to at a glance tell if I am looking at a .razor file (Purple) or a .razor.cs file (Teal).  This is would be an extremely helpful feature for Code behind development.   Thanks for all your help Dou.

Dou, I made a feature request.  Please upvote https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Enable-Persistant-Colors-on-Tabs/10783071?

You can use my (commercial) Tabs Studio extension to create and use persistent tab coloring rules: https://tabsstudio.com/documentation/style.html
